# How can I create different web.config transform for my publish profiles

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC4 project template to create a project.
When I'm developing I'm working on local SQL Server Express instance.
I would like to change the connection string when I publish my site to the hosting provider.

How can I choose the transformation to use, it's not debug or release.

Thank you,
Ido

Comment: This article should be able to guide you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg454290